# Can't access object field after eager loading in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

When I'm trying to eager load my Model with relation like that:

```
$plants = Plant::with('history')
    ->get()
    ->where('user_id', auth()->id());
```

I want to modify those extracted dates with my function like that:

```
foreach ($plants as $plant) {
        $plant->watered_at = self::getDateForHumans($plant->history->watered_at);
        $plant->fertilized_at = self::getDateForHumans($plant->history->fertilized_at);
    }
```

I get this kind of error:

> ErrorException
> Trying to get property 'watered_at' of non-object

but if I try to debug it by dd() function i get a positive result

```
   dd(self::getDateForHumans($plant->history->watered_at));
```

[dd() result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkAuu.)

Does anybody know how to fix it or what is the workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems your history has no `watered_at` member, so it comes to this error.

Check first if you can access this member with

```
if(isset($plant->history->watered_at)){
    $plant->watered_at = self::getDateForHumans($plant->history->watered_at);
}
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you, turned out some records did not have a date value in the DB.